# Windows 10: leave only one language per one keyboard layout

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

I have Windows 10 Pro 64-bit. Recently I performed clean installation. Although updates are not finished yet (feature update constantly can't be installed now for some reason, I'll try something and then make separate question for this).

I have three keyboard languages: English, Russian and Ukrainian.

But for some reason Ukrainian keyboard layout has two languages: Ukrainian and Russian, switching between which is via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

I want to leave only Ukrainian here. How can I do it?

I tried digging through "Change language settings", tried deleting Ukrainian layout and adding it again, I also deleted Russian input method for Ukrainian layout. But it keeps having two languages there.

I **certainly remember** that on my old Windows 10 there were only Ukrainian language underneath Ukrainian keyboard layout. But I don't remember how I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared after all Windows updates were installed successfully.